# Sharepoint certification validity

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have completed SharePoint 2010 certification (070-573). I want to know that what will be the validity of certificate.Means is there any expiry date of that certification.if so then after expiration it will not have any value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the [IT Certifications Site](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-in/certification-overview.aspx) Says about this

Microsoft Certifications are valuable in the market and will remain valuable as long as companies are using the technologies covered in the certification. Over time, certifications will be withdrawn and eventually will transition to a “legacy” status. Legacy Microsoft Certifications will appear on your transcript designated as such. Refer to the withdrawn certifications page for the most current information regarding status.